# GitHub API - Get the number of branches of a repo without listing all its branches

Tags: github-api

I'm currently writing a small project using the GitHub API v3.

I'm constantly doing a calculation based on the number of branches a repo contains. I can't seem to find a way to do so without also requesting to [list all the branches of that repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-branches). The need to request that repo's branches adds unnecessary running time, especially when dealing with hundreds of repos, containing dozens of branches each.

The apparent lack of ability to do so caught me by a small surprise, since a quite similar operation, getting the number of repos of an organization, is easily available by doing so:

1. [Get an organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#get-an-organization). e.g. `GET https://api.github.com/orgs/cloudify-cosmo`, using proper [GitHub authentication credentials](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication).
2. Assuming the authentication was successful, in the response body there are two fields named `public_repos` and `total_private_repos`
3. To get the number of repos, just add the values of these two fields.

So, am I missing something? Is there a similarly-convenient way (or any way at all) of getting the number of branches of a repo without having to list its branches?

Comment: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches` returns an array, can you not just use the length of that?

Comment: I can do that, but that, as I specified, requires me to list all the branches of that repo. I would like to get the number of branches without having to ask for exrta information, just like getting the number of repos per organization using only the fields of `GET /orgs/:org`, without having also to deal with a repo request, e.g. `GET /orgs/:org/repos`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such attribute currently.

However, there's a neat trick you can use to avoid fetching all pages. If you set `per_page` to `1`, then each page will contain 1 item and the number of pages (revealed by the last page) will also tell you the total number of items:

https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

So, with just one request -- you can get the total number of branches. For example, if you fetch this URL and inspect the Link header:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/branches?per_page=1
```

then you'll notice that the `Link` header is:

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/repositories/1725199/branches?per_page=1&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/1725199/branches?per_page=1&page=28>; rel="last"
```

This tells you that there are 28 pages of results, and because there is one item per page -- the total number of branches is 28.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to get branch count easily :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "google", name: "gson") {
    refs(first: 0, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22google%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22gson%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs(first%3A%200%2C%20refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

which gives :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "refs": {
        "totalCount": 13
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you are doing this on multiple repo, it's also more straightforward with GraphQL as you can build the query with different [aliases](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) per repo & use only one request to get branch count for all of these :

```graphql
{
  fetch: repository(owner: "github", name: "fetch") {
    ...RepoFragment
  }
  hub: repository(owner: "github", name: "hub") {
    ...RepoFragment
  }
  scientist: repository(owner: "github", name: "scientist") {
    ...RepoFragment
  }
}

fragment RepoFragment on Repository {
  refs(first: 0, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
    totalCount
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20fetch%3A%20repository(owner%3A%20%22github%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22fetch%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...RepoFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20hub%3A%20repository(owner%3A%20%22github%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22hub%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...RepoFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20scientist%3A%20repository(owner%3A%20%22github%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22scientist%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...RepoFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20RepoFragment%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20refs(first%3A%200%2C%20refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: I had trouble with this query on a private repo until I gave my "Personal Access Token" full repo access. If you get a count of 0 returned and you have branches check you permissions

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple power shell utility based on Avia's Answer. Hope it will help someone in future. Though it is in powershel can be adopted in any other language as well.

````
#$response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/branches?per_page=1

$response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/branches?per_page=1

#https://github.com/angular/angular

$numberOfBranchesString = $response.Headers.link.Split(";")[1].Split(",")[1].Split("&")[1].Split("=")[1];

$numberOfBranches = $numberOfBranchesString.Substring(0, $numberOfBranchesString.length-1);

$numBranch = $numberOfBranches -as [int];

$loopToRunBranch = $numBranch/10 + 1


$remainingBranches = $numBranch%10;

for($i=0; $i -lt $loopToRunBranch; $i++) {
    
    if($i -lt $loopToRunBranch -1 ) {
    #    $response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/branches?per_page=10"
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/branches?page=$($i+1)&per_page=10"
    
        echo $response
    }
    else {
        $remainingBranches = $numberOfBranches%10
    #    $response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/branches?per_page=$remainingBranches"
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/branches?page=$($i+1)&per_page=$remainingBranches"
    
        echo "$i from Else $response"
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

the `branches?per_page=1` trick works but is slow

in my case (200K remote branches) it is 6x slower than parsing the webinterface

this makes sense, because the webinterface is requested more often than a tricky rest api request, so the webinterface is cached

plus, parsing the webinterface gives multiple numbers: number of... branches, tags, commits, stars, watching, forks

this could be optimized further by requesting only the first N bytes of the webinterface

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# get the number of git branches from github

owner=milahu
repo=opensubtitles-scraper-new-subs

# 6 seconds
echo api
time \
num_branches=$(
  curl -s -I "https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/branches?per_page=1" |
  grep ^link |
  sed -E 's/.*page=([0-9]+)>; rel="last"$/\1/'
)
echo "num_branches $num_branches"

# 1 second
echo webui
time \
read num_branches num_tags num_commits num_stars num_watching num_forks < <(
  curl -s https://github.com/$owner/$repo |
  grep -E '<strong>[0-9,]+</strong>' |
  sed -E 's/.*>(.*)<.*/\1/' |
  tr -d , |
  tr $'\n' ' '
)

echo "num_branches $num_branches"
echo "num_tags $num_tags"
echo "num_commits $num_commits"
echo "num_stars $num_stars"
echo "num_watching $num_watching"
echo "num_forks $num_forks"
```